# QED - running of coupling (beta function)

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics, renormalization

I am a little confused about the way most textbooks and notes I've read find the beta function for QED. They find it by looking at how the photon propagator varies with momentum $q$, in particular in the context of a $2\rightarrow2$ scattering process which is proportional to $e^2$, and arguing that the moving in the amplitude of the propagator can be interpreted in the movement of the value of the square of the coupling (e.g. Peskin and Schroeder pages 245-247).

In $\varphi^4$ theory, the story is rather different. Instead, we look at how the vertex amplitude varies with momentum, and the renormalisation of the field and mass is unrelated.

Can we not take a similar approach to determining the beta function for QED, i.e. look at how the vertex amplitude varies with momentum?

Comment: In $\phi^{4}$ theory, you can choose the renormalization conditions so that the vertex amplitude is precisely the amplitude for $2\rightarrow 2$ scattering at zero kinetic energy.  Then the $\beta$-function measure how this changes with the external momentum scale.

Comment: Right, so can we do the same for the QED vertex, i.e. find the QED $\beta$-function by looking at how the amplitude of the vertex changes with, say, photon momentum?

Comment: I still need to carry out the full calculation, but I think the answer to this question is no. Taking an experimental point of view, the coupling strength is obtainable from scattering data, which a single three-point vertex doesn't describe. Instead, I think carrying out the full calculation of the four-electron four-point function will yield the correct beta function.